# Paste range from word in mail body including the format

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, paste

I'm working on a mail merge macro and I'm trying to copy the text from my word document including the format in the mail body unfortunately it doesn't accept the range.paste function there.
Looking forward to any advice.

```
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    oWord.Documents.Open FileName:="*\Flightticket.docx", ReadOnly:=True
    Set oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument
    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0)
    oWord.Visible = False
    oRange.Copy

*
*
*
           With oMail
               .To = oContact.Email1Address
               .Subject = Left(oDoc.Name, Len(oDoc.Name) - 5) & " " & mText
               .GetInspector.Activate 'Signatur
               olOldBody = .HTMLBody
               'The content of the document is used as the body for the email
                .HTMLBody = oRange.Paste  & olOldBody               'Here is the error
             End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now worked around the problem with adding html code to my word document and included the whole content without copy-paste. This worked out pretty good.

```
.HTMLBody = oDoc.Content & olOldBody
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.HTMLBody = oRange.FormattedText  & olOldBody
```

Comment: thank you it doesn't cause an error but also doesn't aste the format with the text